# Serving different media files based on view port size

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-variables, viewport

I'm working on a Laravel App and I would like to serve the content based on the user's viewport size. My app requires user login.

When the user logs in I'll also get the device view port size and store it in the session variables. So whenever a particular view is requested I can check the view port dimensions stored in the session and serve the content based on that.

**My question: Is there any better way to achieve what I want?**

**Edit**

I know responsive design. The trouble I'm facing with the CSS media queries is the tables. I've hard time making the tables responsive and present them meaningfully. And I've several pages with table data in my app. So I thought I can use the above approach.

I can even optimize the mobile pages to load the fewer resources. I don't want all the features available on desktop to be in mobile. This means that right now my webpage has hidden content, unused plugins and resources on the mobile devices.

**So instead of loading the content and 'hiding' it, why not just load the minimum data(and resources, plugins) required for the mobile devices?**

**Edit 2**

After further research I found answers to my questions. I found that there is whole new concept of [dynamic serving](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/dynamic-serving), which is adopted by most of the large sites. Often it is difficult to achieve everything with CSS media queries. And the css code can get cluttered.

Also the frameworks like Laravel makes it easy to manage the different views. So in such cases dynamic serving can be helpful.

Comment: *best practices* are opinionated. You *best practices* might be my nightmare or vice versa, for this reason I feel your question will be closed unless you edit it.

Comment: **Cough** It may now be classed as too broad, do you have a specific issue? **Cough**

Comment: Yes, there's definitely a better way. It's not even subjective or disputed either. The entire reason that Media Queries in CSS were created was to support the Responsive Design Pattern. Any common CSS framework provides responsive breakpoints that allow you to alter, and even show completely different, based on the viewport of the user. If you're rolling your own CSS, then you can make your own. But whatever you do, don't go down this route unless you've got a great reason for it.